passing parameter to a progress 4gl file using prowin32
I am trying to pass multiple input parameters using prowin32 . But i am not able to find out the correct way of passing multiple parameters.
This is the code of my *.p file
define input parameter param1 as character no-undo.
define input parameter param2 as character no-undo.
message param1 param2 
view-as alert-box.    

and I am trying the below command in proenv
prowin32.exe -p D:\proj\myfolder\sample.p -param "1stValue","SecondValue" -clientlog D:\proj\myfolder\pf\lg.log

I tried removing the quotation marks of the input parameters but I am still getting error saying
mismatched parameters passed to the routine


Another Alternative is to use a Parameter "pf" file .
Prowin32.exe -pf c:\test\myprog.pf
Inside myprog.pf file 
-p c:\test\mystartupProgram.p
-param "Param1, Param2, Param2" 
-db myDB
-H localhost 
-S 5000


Use -param “1stValue,2ndValue”.
In your code you then use:
P1 = entry( 1, session:parameter ).
P2 = entry( 2, session:parameter ).

Rather than the “define input parameter…” statements.

You’re welcome. It is traditional to mark an answer as correct when it solves your problem. In that way future readers will be able to more quickly resolve similar problems.

you cannot parse mulitple parameter in progress
just one SESSION:PARAMETER
we did it with a own .p file
that calls the .p from the session:parameter
prowin32.exe start
prowin32.exe -p D:\proj\myfolder\startpgm.p -param "D:\proj\myfolder\sample.p,1stValue,SecondValue" -clientlog D:\proj\myfolder\pf\lg.lo

startpgm.p
DEFINE VARIABLE hCall AS HANDLE    NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE i     AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.

CREATE CALL hCall.
hCall:CALL-NAME = ENTRY(1,SESSION:PARAMETER). // path
hCall:NUM-PARAMETERS = NUM-ENTRIES(SESSION:PARAMETER) - 1. // Num-Parameter

IF NUM-ENTRIES(SESSION:PARAMETER) > 1 THEN DO:

   DO i = 2 TO NUM-ENTRIES(SESSION:PARAMETER):

      // Parameter
      hCall:SET-PARAMETER(i - 1, "CHARACTER", "INPUT", ENTRY(i,SESSION:PARAMETER)).

   END.

END.

hCall:INVOKE. // Start


Thanks for the solution!!!...My problem is solved now
